# Making a targeting system in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

This is a "tower defense" game. I have a class called soldier.

```
    if(wave1==true){
        for(int i=0;i<(wave*10);i++){
            handler.addObject(new soldier(getX(), getY(), ID.soldier, handler));
            try {
            //  System.out.println(i);
                Thread.sleep(500);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }

        }
        wave++;
        wave1=false;
        try {
        //  System.out.println(i);
            Thread.sleep(WT);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
        }
```

Every time this code is called is the soldier gets spawned 10 times for every wave, but I have one issue. I would like the tower 1 to kill the furthest soldier in range. The code for the killing:

```
    private void collision() {
    for(int i=0; i< Handler.object.size();i++){
        GameObject tempObject = Handler.object.get(i);
        if(tempObject.getID()== ID.ST1){
            if(getBounds().intersects(tempObject.getBounds())){         
                Hsol=(Hsol-1);

                if(Hsol<=0){
                    handler.removeObject(this);

                }
            }               
        }
        }
    }
```

So I know I need to do a distance formula to find which ones closer, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Please clarify, You want two things. 1.that soldier 1 will not get killed. 2. That the tower will 1st kill the farthest soldier in range. Is this correct?

Comment: I didn't read further than `if(wave1=true)`. You probably want `if (wave1 == true)`, or much better: `if (wave1)`. I would also try to choose much better names: having a boolean wave1 and an integer wave is quite confusing. WT, Hsol, ID don't respect naming conventions, don't mean anything, and make your code very hard to read, even for you.

Comment: @JBNizet i have the spawning system id like. i just need help getting the targeting system for the tower to work correctly.

Comment: @MarrieteCowby12 sorry i didnt catch that mistake while typing this. but the answer to your qustion is. i would like the tower to kill the furthest soldier in range

Comment: Why not iterate through all soldiers in a loop and check which one has the farthest range and then call the kill method on that one, would that work?

Comment: @MarrieteCowby12 that wouldnt work

Comment: explain why it wouldnt work please

Comment: Hi, The Gaming Koala, please remove SOLVED and the solution from the question, edit your answer instead and accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given two points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2), the distance formula is

√[(x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2]

So, using that formula, you can loop through each soldier and see which one is closest to the point that the attack is coming from.

Comment: i understand that. id like the tower to hit the furthest on the path. (not a straight line) and attack that one. when their are other soldiers in the boundary but not the furthest

Comment: So this is like a tower defense type of thing, where the soldiers are going around obstacles or are on a fixed path, and the ones physically closer to a spot aren't necessarily the ones that are actually going to get there first?

Comment: yes its towerdefense, (i forgot to put that in the explaination ill edit it right now)

Comment: It's not the most efficient thing, but I guess you could simulate the movement of the soldiers to see which one would get to the place first if they were left alone.

Comment: how would i go about doing that?

Comment: That depends on how the soldiers move, I guess.

Comment: this is how i move them

Comment: if (x==218&&y==66){
   reg=true;
   velX=xs;
   velY=d;
  }

Comment: xs is when x is still d is down

Comment: how would i find the first instance of soldier? then if their isnt then the next? thats the problem with what i tried doing.

Comment: If you just want to know which soldier spawned first, maybe you could have a static variable in Soldier that counts the number of soldiers you have and an instance variable that keeps track of which soldier number this is, and in the constructor you set the instance variable equal to the static variable, and increment the static variable.

Comment: my issue is labeling the instances the soldiers spawn with handler.addObject(new soldier(getX(), getY(), ID.soldier, handler)); and get removed with handler.removeObject(this);

Comment: the command killing the soldiers when their health is lower than 1 is in the soldier class. if i make instances static it would make all the instances of the class the same

Comment: I was talking about having just one static variable to count the number of soldiers, so you'd know what to number the next one.

Comment: if(this==handler.object.get(3)){
    if(getBounds().intersects(tempObject.getBounds())){ 
     Hsol=(Hsol-1);
     
     if(Hsol<=0){
      handler.removeObject(this);
      HUD.coin=(HUD.coin+100);
      instances=(instances-1);
      
      //System.out.println(HUD.coin);
     }
    }
    
    
     }

Answer (score 0):

```
private void collision() {
    for(int i=0; i< Handler.object.size();i++){
        GameObject tempObject = Handler.object.get(i);
        if(tempObject.getID()== ID.ST1){
        if(this==handler.object.get(3)){
            if(getBounds().intersects(tempObject.getBounds())){ 
                Hsol=(Hsol-1);

                if(Hsol<=0){
                    handler.removeObject(this);
                    HUD.coin=(HUD.coin+100);
                    instances=(instances-1);

                    //System.out.println(HUD.coin);
                }
            }


                }
            }               
        }
        }
```